# WCF json POST Request Method:GET and 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, wcf

hello my problem is that i use microsoft visual studio for creating wcf webservice and when i run on microsoft visual studio everything is fine and works. But i have to connect to webservice outside so when i do that its not connect. so first its give me crossDomain error so i change webconfig and i get value from outside html file but i cant post. I gave this errro :

```
GET http://localhost:3281/UserService.svc/SetUser?callback=jQuery11020891759618…20%22usertype%22:%20%22%22,%20%22email%22%20:%20%22%22%20}&_=1386343306675 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

my english is not good so i will add my code and source file you can see yourself.

first my javascript :

```
    <script>

function btnSubmit() {
$.support.corps = true;



        $.ajax({
              crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:3281/UserService.svc/SetUser",
            data: '{ "usertype": "' + $("#txtuserName").val() + '", "email" : "' + $("#txtuserEmail").val() + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",

            success: function (r) { alert("Successfully Registered!!!"); },
            error: function (e) { alert(e.statusText); }
        });
    }

    function btnRetrieve() {
    $.support.corps = true;
        $.ajax({
              crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            type: "GET",  
            url: "http://localhost:3281/UserService.svc/GetUser",
            data: { name: $("#find").val() },
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (r) {
                if (r != null) $("#DisplayResult").html(r.Email);
                 else
                 $("#DisplayResult").html("Bilgi yok");
            },
            error: function (e) { alert(e.statusText); }
        });
    }



  </script>
```

my service content :

```
namespace JQueryCallToWcf
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class UserService
    {
        // Create a List of User type and add temporary data. This List will be used a 
        // Fake Repository for Data Tranasaction. In real world we can replace this with 
        // EntityFramework or Linq2Sql Data Model for actual data transactions.

        public static List<User> lstUsers = new List<User>()
            {
                new User() { Name="Rami", Email="Rami@Rami.com"},
                new User() { Name="Bill", Email="Bill@Bill.com"},
                new User() { Name="Mark", Email="Mark@Mark.com"},
            };

        // We have two service methods - SetUser and GetUser, which sets and gets 
        // user from fake repository.

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void SetUser(string usertype, string email)
        {
            lstUsers.Add(new User() { Name = usertype, Email = email });
        }

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public User GetUser(string name)
        {
            User op = lstUsers.Where(p => p.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
            return op;
        }
    }

    // This is the User Class, holding properties for Name and email.

    [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }



}
```

and i add webconfig this for crossdomain

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonp" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="JQueryCallToWcf.UserService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonp"
                  contract="JQueryCallToWcf.UserService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

i give you my solution file its working , also i give you outside html file get is working post not.

http://s3.dosya.tc/server14/y4vqdP/Desktop.rar.html

Comment: firstly it should be `$.support.cors = true;`

Comment: it is about binding i give permission for cross domain it's okey. i will share answer.

Answer (score 0):

i used jsonp and i change binding in web.config. It is working now.

You can try like that :

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="bitness32" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```